# VBA - Error 438 object doesn't support... CenterAlign captions of command buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an error 438 "object doesn't support property..." screenshot below.  My code below:  Objective is to center-align the caption/text of all command buttons on Userform1.  Why I'm getting this error?  How to fix it?

```
Option Explicit

         '<<<<<<<<<<< Adapted from http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=330

#If VBA7 Then
      Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong& Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long)
      Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong& Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long)
#Else
      Private Declare Function GetWindowLong& Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long)
      Private Declare Function SetWindowLong& Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long)
#End If

'--------------------------------------------

Public Enum BUTTON_STYLE
    BS_CENTER = &H300&
    BS_LEFT = &H100&
    BS_RIGHT = &H200&
    BS_TOP = &H400&
End Enum

'--------------------------------------------

Private Const GWL_STYLE& = (-16)

Public Sub AlignCommandButtonText(Button As Object, Style As BUTTON_STYLE)
      Dim lHwnd As Long
      On Error Resume Next
      lHwnd = Button.hwnd
      Dim lWnd As Long
      Dim lRet As Long
      If lHwnd = 0 Then Exit Sub
      lWnd = GetWindowLong(lHwnd, GWL_STYLE)
      lRet = SetWindowLong(Command1.hwnd, GWL_STYLE, Style Or lWnd)
      Button.Refresh
End Sub


'--------------------------------------------

Public Sub CenterAlignButtons()
    For Each control_Object In UserForm1.Controls
       If TypeName(control_Object) = "CommandButton" Then
         Set Button = control_Object
         Button.Refresh        '<<<<<<< This method of calling is wrong, causing the error...?
         DoEvents
       End If
    Next
End Sub

'--------------------------------------------
```

[Error 438...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZht3.jpg)

[Before running language code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao9od.jpg)

[After running language code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Evo.jpg)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `AlignCommandButtonText` somewhere in your code?

Comment: A button has no `Refresh`-method. What do you want to achieve? Maybe just call `AlignCommandButtonText Button, BS_CENTER`

Comment: Thomas - Your proposed call code didn't work.  Tim - To answer your question, please see two screenshots below -- Buttons, RunKoreanLanguageCode, ReturnToEnglishCode, and then Buttons in English alignment got changed!

Comment: Still need a solution please?